# How to simulate mouse button 4 and mouse button 5 click in C#?

Tags: c#, console-application, mouseevent

I am trying to create a tool to manipulate user32.dll. I want to add a function that you can simulate a mouse click, but i want to add all the available mouse buttons, like M4 (mouse button 4) and M5 (mouse button 5). I didn't find any documentation showing how to simulate these buttons. So, i decided to ask here in Stack Overflow to see if someone knows how to do this.

I tried looking for documentation, but i didn't find anything that answered my question.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.Mouse5.html

Comment: I am trying to do this in a console application, so, i think that Unity Engine won't work.

Comment: So sorry. Didn't catch that. Anyway, how are you getting the normal mouse clicks in the first place?

Comment: I am using user32.dll. To simulate the mouse events i use mouse_event(). In this function i put a hexadecimal code that represents the mouse button, like `0x00000002` (mouse button 1 down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the cursor position, you can send a message to a window that the extra mouse buttons are clicked. You most likely want WM_XBUTTONDOWN and WM_XBUTTONUP.

WM_XBUTTONDOWN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-xbuttondown

WM_XBUTTONUP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-xbuttonup

```
 [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(System.Drawing.Point p);


IntPtr windowHandel = WindowFromPoint(new System.Drawing.Point(500, 500));

//Extra mouse button one
SendMessage(windowHandel, 0x020B, (IntPtr)0x00010000, new IntPtr());//Click
SendMessage(windowHandel, 0x020C, (IntPtr)0x00010000, new IntPtr());//Release

//Extra mouse button two click
SendMessage(windowHandel, 0x020B, (IntPtr)0x00020000, new IntPtr());//Click
SendMessage(windowHandel, 0x020C, (IntPtr)0x00020000, new IntPtr());//Release
```

Comment: I am using a console application, so i think that forms wont work

Comment: It looks like it's hard to add a WinForms reference to Console apps in newer versions of .NET. There are other ways to get the cursor position besides Cursor.Position. I've edited my answer to use a fixed point (500, 500) and also to correct mistakes in the answer.

Comment: But will this script work  with M4 and M5 buttons? I actually have M1, M2 and M3 buttons script.

Comment: Yes. I've tested this on backward and forward navigation in chrome.